# Temporarily retiring character

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic

One of the players in a game I GM is going to be leaving the country for a while.  What options do I have (story-wise) for having his character leave the party in a way that still leaves the door open for him to come back later?  I want to avoid the standard "he goes off on a side-quest and then rejoins the party when he's done" trope, because they are currently on a high-stakes, "save-the-world"-type arc, and it doesn't really make sense for someone to risk that failing for a side-quest of lesser importance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Please check out our [tour] to see how we work here. We're a Q&A site focused on questions that can have a single best or correct answer, and we don't handle general idea/brainstorm requests, so I've closed this. (Please see also [Why do we close questions asking for a range of practical options?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7582/1204))

Comment: @starscream_disco_party Please see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for why your comment was removed.

Comment: @doppelgreener: Thank you for the welcome, and for the warning.  If you don't mind, what additional information would you like to see to make the question less broad?  I read the link you posted, and I understand why "menu" questions aren't a good fit, but asking "how can I find out..." as suggested there doesn't really make sense for this particular question.

Comment: Not every question can be made to fit here, if the problem to be solved is inherently a type we can’t help with. In that case, this is the wrong site for your needs. See “[I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321)” for what to do next.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll definitely take a look at those resources.  Thanks again for taking the time to hear me out.